# SQL Query to Linq query with cast as real

Tags: sql, linq

Hello I now use the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT DateTime, CAST(FillLevel as REAL) as FillLevel, " +
                  "CAST(Temperature as REAL) as Temperature, " +
                  "CAST(Latitude as REAL) as Latitude, " +
                  "CAST(Longitude as REAL) as Longitude, " +
                  "CAST(Unit as REAL) as Unit from Message
```

Now I want to get the same result with a Linq query. What's the best way to CAST a type to REAL?

I now have the following:

```
var tempquery = from m in context.Message
                        where m.Unit == 1
                        select new
                        {
                            DateTime = m.DateTime,
                            FillLevel = m.FillLevel,
                            Temperature = m.Temperature,
                            Latitude = m.Latitude,
                            Longitude = m.Longitude,
                            Unit = m.Unit
                        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# equivalent of SQL's `real` is `float` (which is the type alias of `Single`). You can add the type casts to the query:

```cs
from m in context.Message
where m.Unit == 1
select new
{
    DateTime = m.DateTime,
    FillLevel = (float)m.FillLevel,
    Temperature = (float)m.Temperature,
    Latitude = (float)m.Latitude,
    Longitude = (float)m.Longitude,
    Unit = (float)m.Unit
};
```

Depending on the ORM you're using you will see this translated in something like:

```
SELECT CAST([m].[FillLevel] AS real)
...
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the type casting in 'Where' clause? @Gert